# Not understanding the boost error_codes

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

My goal is to replace a very very simple winsock implementation, which worked perfectly, with a platform-agnostic version (for windows and linux).  Using boost to provide that abstration layer, mostly since it's used elsewhere in the group so, while in Rome.  It's a neat library / framework, so this is not a rant.. just not "getting" some of it, which might expose some fundamental lack of understanding.. please help me to gain such understanding.

What I had before was a very simple bing-[bang|bong] communication between a server and client.  Client sent *bing*, server would reply with *bang* if all was ok, *bong* otherwise.  Didn't need any more than that, though the capability to add on was there.

Now, going to boost, I am finding all sorts of gotchas, primarily coming down to not having been exposed to it very much yet, but I'm learning (I wish visual studio 2005's intellisense would catalog it to make it easier to navigate).  I found that the read() method would block until the connection timed out, rendering inoperative, the goal of having this continuous communication.  I think the socket.read_some( ) method might help me... attempting to try that.

I also am trying to refactor the connection-establishment code for use as a re-connect method too.. and that is where I am running into issues.

Consider the following:

```
boost::system::error_code ServiceMonitorThread::ConnectToPeer(
    tcp::socket &socket,
    tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
{
    boost::system::error_code error;
    int tries = 0;

    for (; tries < maxTriesBeforeAbort; tries++)
    {
        boost::asio::connect(socket, endpoint_iterator, error);

        if (error && error != boost::system::errc::success)
        {
            // Error connecting to service... may not be running?
            string errMsg = boost::system::system_error(error).what();
            cerr << errMsg << endl;
            boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(200));
        }
    }

    if (tries == maxTriesBeforeAbort)
    {
        return boost::system::errc::host_unreachable;
    }

    return error;
}
```

And the snippet (not yet debugged, might not be using the read_some() correctly) making use of the above:

```
socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(response), error);

switch (error)
{
case boost::system::errc::success:
    break;

case boost::asio::error::eof:
    // Connection was dropped, re-connect to the service.
    error = ConnectToPeer(socket, endpoint_iterator);
    if (error && error == boost::system::errc::host_unreachable)
    {
        TerminateProgram();
    }
    continue;

default:
    // Other error while receiving from socket
    string errMsg = boost::system::system_error(error).what();
    cerr << errMsg << endl;
    retry++;
    continue;
}
```

Now, I get that the error_code and errc::errc_t are not the same thing... but you see the intent of what I am trying to accomplish.  How do I realize the goal of the above while working within the intent of the boost framework?

Comment: I personally feel that boost socket implementation is extremely cumbersome. If the only goal is to make the app cross-platform, just replace WSA* functions with their BSD counterparts (under some of the preprocessor defines) and be done with that :)

Comment: It's not so much the socket bit that I am looking for help on, rather, it's how to reconcile the error handling / error codes.  Seems they come from all over the place - of only what I have seen to date, there is boost::asio:error, boost::system::error_code, boost::system::errc ... and it's not clear to me how I can boil those down to one "thing" I can check.

Comment: Boost Asio is indeed _quite_ cumbersome. Mostly a case of being overdesigned for simple tasks, I think. It may be ideal for some complex tasks, I just haven't seen those yet.

Comment: It makes asynchronous comms extremely easy and painless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::system::error_code` contains both a category and an error code. It's purpose is to provide a heterogeneous type which can contain the disparate error codes of different subsystems.

Noting that `system::error_code` is convertible to bool, and will only evaluate to true if there is an error:

```
auto bytes_read = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(response), error);
if (error)
{
  if (error == make_error_code(boost::asio::error::eof))
  {
    // Connection was dropped, re-connect to the service.
    error = ConnectToPeer(socket, endpoint_iterator);
    if (error && error == make_error_code(boost::system::errc::host_unreachable))
    {
        TerminateProgram();
    }
    continue;
  }
  else 
  {
    cerr << error.message() << endl;
    retry++;
    continue;
  }
}
```

see boost::system for description of the ADL function `make_error_code`.

Comment: I will look at that and explore the modified code you posted, thank you for taking the time. One question.. the error_code class appears to have an operator= defined which calls make_error_code internally, yet, when I issue `error = boost::system::errc::host_unreachable`, it fails to compile with "binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'boost::system::errc::errc_t' (or there is no acceptable conversion)".  What am I failing to understand?

Comment: "Remarks: This operator shall not participate in overload resolution unless is_error_code_enum<ErrorCodeEnum>::value is true.". It's probably a good idea to understand `boost::system_error` before you start. It's very similar to `std::system_error`.

Comment: in addition, there are some informative examples on the boost website. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html have a look at the blocking chat client.

Comment: I've been trying to read through a lot of the samples there.. informative, but a tough slog to make sense of it all.  I'm down to what I hope is the last hurdle (I have yet to read up on the boost::system_error, but I will shortly).  The code `boost::array<char, 10> response;
auto bytes_read = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(response, 10), error);` gives me "error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int" when I try to compile.  That code looks like all of the samples I've seen, so I am not understanding this error message in this case.

Comment: ah - are you compiling with c++11? if not you'll need to replace `auto` with `size_t`

Comment: That did it!  I read up on the system_error, but am failing to see the connection between that and not being able to use the operator= in error_code.

Comment: it's not related. system::error_code::operator= will accept an enum on the right hand side, but only if the is_error_code<T> traits class has been specialised for the enum type. Oddly it seems that asio::errc has not had this specialisation created for it. I don't know why.

Comment: "only if the is_error_code<T> traits class has been specialised for the enum type".  And that is where we lost him, Your Honour. :)  What does that mean and, how would a traits class be specialized (and for which enum type - errc_t?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96735/discussion-between-richard-hodges-and-jon).